# Heirarchy in Euler rotations

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

Why is there necessarily a hierarchy in Euler rotations?

For example I need to decide that I want

```
x to affect y and z
z to affect y
y to affect nothing.
```

What if I wanted to have something like:

```
x to affect y and z
z to affect x and y
y to affect nothing
```

(x, y and z refer to rotations about x, y and z)

I understand for a physical gimbal there is a restriction, but that need not be necessary for a computer graphics system, right?

Answer (score 1):

Euler rotations work around the axes. This is represented in 3 angles (rot_x, rot_y, rot_z). The order of the rotation needs to be determined as the order affects the result.

For example, if we have a point (1, 0, 0) and we rotate 90 degrees around the Y and then 90 degrees around the Z, then the result will be

```
v1 = (1,0,0)
v2 = rotate_y(v1, 90) # v2 = (0,0,1)
v3 = rotate_z(c2, 90) # v3 = (0,0,1)
```

When doing the other order first Z and then Y, the result is different:

```
v1 = (1,0,0)
v2 = rotate_z(v1, 90) # v2 = (0,1,0)
v3 = rotate_y(c2, 90) # v3 = (0,1,0)
```

In computer graphics systems, quaternion rotations are often used, which allows rotation around any axis. This then solves many of the problems with Euler systems.